# Solving for only half the solution in NonlinearSolve.jl

Tags: julia, solver

```
using NonlinearSolve, LinearAlgebra, Plots

# Parameters: p = [h, \omega]
N=15

g(u,p) = p[1]*Tridiagonal(fill(1,N), fill(-2,N+1), fill(1,N))*u - u.^3 - p[2]*u 

probg = NonlinearProblem{false}(g, [0.3; fill(0.3, N-1); 0.3], [0.6, -0.4])

solver = solve(probg, NewtonRaphson(), reltol = 1e-9)
```

In the above code, I utilize the `NonlinearSolve.jl` package to solve an elliptic nonlinear problem. The solutions are generally symmetric. Below is the output of the above code. Note the symmetry of the solution.

To save computation time, I would like to solve for only half the solution. How do I specify that in this package?

Example:

```
 9.165610097608932e-13
 2.704903846479506e-12
 4.63792285826381e-12
 5.947401561035362e-12
 6.6334560728468356e-12
 6.943120557656446e-12
 7.068988650731425e-12
 7.112134991181518e-12
 7.112134991181518e-12
 7.068988650731425e-12
 6.9431205305513916e-12
 6.633456045741781e-12
 5.947401533930308e-12
 4.63792285826381e-12
 2.7049038871370876e-12
 9.165610097608932e-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a closure over the `f` function of the nonlinear solve that takes in the half that's being solved, fills in the other half, and then calculates the full residual.